# How can I show Woocommerce pricing variable like this on my site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to show woocom product variale like this image. Is there any way I can do that in Woocom?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJR27.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible Please use a plugin dropdown to a checkbox.
Here is an example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpc-variations-radio-buttons/